# How to boost site performance for ONE day?

Tags: wordpress, performance

I consult with folks on a Wordpress site that is used for an event held once each year. The site runs fine throughout the year. Cache plugins in place, etc...The site is hosted on Hostgator.

However, on the day of the event- usage is off the charts and the site becomes unusable.

Last year I used CloudFlare, which helped. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Please, read the meaning of a tag before you use it (mouseover text explains it). "boost" refers to "c++ boost libraries" and thus is irrelevant to your post. I'll remove the tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is only so much software can do to improve performance. This sound like the server your site is running on is not able to handle all the requests. I suggest you upgrade your server/VPS only for the amount of time that you suspect that huge amount of load, instead of looking into software solutions.

Especially since you only expect this to happen once a year, I think it is financially more appealing to increase server speed for a short period of time, which may cost some money, but will terminate the problem you're facing.

Trying to resolve this only with software, you might not ever be able to reach the results of upgrading your server and it can take a lot of time and research to streamline everything for the best performance.